# Search by date range and by keyword

Tags: php, sql, ajax

For report generation in the project I made I want to use 2 methods:

1. By date range (from date and up to date)
2. By employee ID

While using the above keywords the complete record of the employee should be displayed in that particular range.

For ex- emp1234 is the employee whose record is to be checked between date 20 may 2018 to 30 june 2018. The result must be displayed in between the range

Another thing is that the search can be done either by date or by employee id or both but both should not be compulsory.

the script is as follows:

```
<script>  
      $(document).ready(function(){  
           $.datepicker.setDefaults({  
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'   
           });  
           $(function(){  
                $("#from_date").datepicker();  
                $("#to_date").datepicker();  
           });  
           $('#filter').click(function(){  
                var from_date = $('#from_date').val();  
                var to_date = $('#to_date').val();  
                if(from_date != '' && to_date != '')  
                {  
                     $.ajax({  
                          url:"filter.php",  
                          method:"POST",  
                          data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},  
                          success:function(data)  
                          {  
                               $('#report_table').html(data);  
                          }  
                     });  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                     alert("Please Select Date");  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 </script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_data();

 function load_data(query)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query},
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#report_table').html(data);
   }
  });
 }
 $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
  var search = $(this).val();
  if(search != '')
  {
   load_data(search);
  }
  else
  {
   load_data();
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

I need to combine these two different queries into one.

**filter.php**

```
<?php  
 //filter.php  
 if(isset($_POST["from_date"], $_POST["to_date"]))  
 {  
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ais");  
      $output = '';  
      $query = "  
           SELECT * FROM tbl_employees,tbl_in_time_attendance,tbl_out_time_attendance  WHERE tbl_employees.EmpId=tbl_in_time_attendance.EmpId AND tbl_in_time_attendance.EmpId=tbl_out_time_attendance.EmpId AND tbl_in_time_attendance.date=tbl_out_time_attendance.date AND tbl_in_time_attendance.date AND tbl_out_time_attendance.date  BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND '".$_POST["to_date"]."'  
      ";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
      $cnt=1;     
      $output .= '  
           <table class="table table-bordered">  
                <tr>  
                     <th width="6%">Sr No.</th>  
                     <th width="15%">EMPLOYEE ID</th> 
                     <th width="20%">EMPLOYEE NAME</th>
                     <th width="15%">IN_TIME</th>  
                     <th width="15%">OUT_TIME</th>  
                     <th width="15%">DATE</th> 
                     <th width="25%">WORKING HOURS</th> 
                </tr>  
      ';  
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
      {  
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
           {  
                        $outtime = $row["outtime"];
                        $intime = $row["intime"];
                        $array1 = explode(':', $intime);
                        $array2 = explode(':', $outtime);

                        $minutes1 = ($array1[0] * 60.0 + $array1[1])/60;
                        $minutes2 = ($array2[0] * 60.0 + $array2[1])/60;

                        $diff = round(($minutes2 - $minutes1),1).' hrs';


                $output .= '  
                     <tr>  
                          <td align="center">'. $cnt .'</td>  
                          <td align="center">'. $row["EmpId"] .'</td>  
                          <td align="center">'. $row["FirstName"] . " " . $row["LastName"].'</td> 
                          <td align="center">'. $row["intime"] .'</td>  
                          <td align="center"> '. $row["outtime"] .'</td>  
                          <td align="center">'. $row["date"] .'</td> ';
        if ($diff < 8) {
        $output .= '<td align="center" style="background-color: #F42E2E;"> ' . $diff . ' </td>';
} else {
    $output .= '<td align="center" style="background-color: #55E443;"> ' . $diff . ' </td>';
}
$output .= '</tr>';

          $cnt++;
           } 

      }  
      else  
      {  
           $output .= '  
                <tr>  
                     <td colspan="5">No Record Found</td>  
                </tr>  
           ';  
      }  
      $output .= '</table>';  
      echo $output;  
 }  


 ?>
```

**Fetch.php**

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ais");
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{

 $query = "
          SELECT * FROM tbl_employees,tbl_in_time_attendance,tbl_out_time_attendance  WHERE tbl_employees.EmpId=tbl_in_time_attendance.EmpId AND tbl_in_time_attendance.EmpId=tbl_out_time_attendance.EmpId AND tbl_in_time_attendance.date=tbl_out_time_attendance.date AND tbl_in_time_attendance.date AND tbl_employees.EmpId LIKE '".$_POST["query"]."' ";
}
else
{
 $query = "SELECT * from tbl_employees, tbl_in_time_attendance , tbl_out_time_attendance WHERE tbl_employees.EmpId=tbl_in_time_attendance.EmpId AND tbl_in_time_attendance.EmpId=tbl_out_time_attendance.EmpId AND tbl_in_time_attendance.date=tbl_out_time_attendance.date";  

}
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 $cnt=1;

 $output .= '

   <table class="table table-bordered">  
                <tr>  
                     <th width="6%">Sr No.</th>  
                     <th width="15%">EMPLOYEE ID</th> 
                     <th width="20%">EMPLOYEE NAME</th>
                     <th width="15%">IN_TIME</th>  
                     <th width="15%">OUT_TIME</th>  
                     <th width="15%">DATE</th> 
                     <th width="25%">WORKING HOURS</th> 
                </tr>  
 ';
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $outtime = $row["outtime"];
                        $intime = $row["intime"];
                        $array1 = explode(':', $intime);
                        $array2 = explode(':', $outtime);

                        $minutes1 = ($array1[0] * 60.0 + $array1[1])/60;
                        $minutes2 = ($array2[0] * 60.0 + $array2[1])/60;

                        $diff = round(($minutes2 - $minutes1),1).' hrs';


                $output .= '  
                     <tr>  
                          <td align="center">'. $cnt .'</td>  
                          <td align="center">'. $row["EmpId"] .'</td>  
                          <td align="center">'. $row["FirstName"] . " " . $row["LastName"].'</td> 
                          <td align="center">'. $row["intime"] .'</td>  
                          <td align="center"> '. $row["outtime"] .'</td>  
                          <td align="center">'. $row["date"] .'</td> ';
        if ($diff < 8) {
        $output .= '<td align="center" style="background-color: #F42E2E;"> ' . $diff . ' </td>';
} else {
    $output .= '<td align="center" style="background-color: #55E443;"> ' . $diff . ' </td>';
}
$output .= '</tr>';

          $cnt++;
 }
 }
 else  
      {  
           $output .= '  
                <tr>  
                     <td colspan="5">No Record Found</td>  
                </tr>  
           ';  
      }  
      $output .= '</table>';  
      echo $output;  




?>
```

I want these to separate fetch and filter files into one file.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

please dont delete the question again, i was writing a few minutes and then the question was deleted haha

soo, as you have a filter button which has to be clicked to get the results there are two ways you can choose!

1. you display your table with datatable plugin which means you only need to filter by date and then write the employeeid in the searchbox and you will only see the results for this person WITHOUT having to query it again!
   https://datatables.net/
2. you get the two dates AND your search query by clicking on the filter button which means you will only have one php file (i dont know why you actually want to use fetch & filter).. In your php file you then look if there are only dates submitted OR the query is also submitted:

   ```
   $('#filter').click(function(){  
      var from_date = $('#from_date').val();  
      var to_date = $('#to_date').val();  
      var query = $("#search_text").val();

      if(from_date != '' && to_date != '')  
      {  
        $.ajax({  
             url:"filter.php",  
             method:"POST",  
             data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date, employee: query},  
             success:function(data)  
             {  
                  $('#report_table').html(data);  
             }  
        });  
      }  
      else  
      {  
        alert("Please Select Date");  
      }  
   });
   ```

in php file

```
if(isset($_POST["employee"]) AND $_POST["employee"] != "") {
    // make your sql call with dates AND employeeid
} else {
    // make your sql call only with dates
}
```

depending on how many results you have I'm sure its also possible to dont even have to query again for different dates and instead tweak datatable so that you have one from_date, one to_date and one search field and filter the table after keyup.. see example here: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Comment: if possible can you please provide the code for this

Comment: I cant as you dont tell me the real problem.. what does not work? do you get any errors?

Comment: I changed my code as you said. The date range filter is working but the search query still not search anything

Comment: ah sorry i think its because i had "#searchtext" instead of "#search_text".. please try it by changing that line!

Comment: also please note that my post variable will be employee and yours was query, you can change that to whatever you like more..

Comment: i changed it few seconds ago but if you copied my code then you have the old id.. did you change it?

Comment: hmm then please try at first in the jquery to alert(query); to see if that works, and in your php file (i think you choose $output) put a line inside the search_text section where you just say $output = "test" and see if it goes in the right section.. you could also open the webinspector and see if the query get sent through

Comment: please provide code or links that has the function of both sql queries

Comment: i tried simple datatable logic only to search my data from the database but it didn.t work

Comment: please check this link : https://www.webslesson.info/2017/06/date-range-search-in-datatables-using-php-ajax.html     I tried to run the code but it gives json error something

Comment: if you're querys worked before, then you just have to change them a little so that one searches for results with from_date, to_date AND employee | and the other one only for from_date and to_date..

Comment: do you now use datatables or not?

Comment: if you use datatables you have to read the docs on how to populate the table.. you will need to get the data via json and not normaly outputted but please read first on how to do it..

Comment: i used the datatables for simple search but it didn't work

Comment: thats why I said, read the docs.. datatables are different then outputting your normal table into your table field but im not here to write your complete code.. just learn it now and you will be able to use it for your next projects too.. rewrite your code for datatables if you want to use it and if you have questions, post your new code as a question and tell your problems.. my example is NOT for datatables thats why i wrote 1. datatables, 2. normal search